# Why are values ​different from when I declare my tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to understanding what is happening with my code but I couldn't obtain a solution.

Here is my code:

```py
multipolygon = ((
    (-58.89198482 -13.38147202, -58.89189251 -13.38147271, -58.89189321 -13.38156309, -58.89198552 -13.3815624,
     -58.89207783 -13.38156171, -58.89217014 -13.38156102, -58.89226245 -13.38156032, -58.89235476 -13.38155963, 
     -58.89244706 -13.38155894, -58.89253937 -13.38155825, -58.89263168 -13.38155756, -58.89263097 -13.38146719, 
     -58.89253867 -13.38146788, -58.89244636 -13.38146857, -58.89235405 -13.38146926, 
     -58.89226174 -13.38146995, -58.89216943 -13.38147064, -58.89207712 -13.38147133, 
     -58.89198482 -13.38147202)
    ), 
 (
    (-58.89484849 -13.38172171, -58.89484919 -13.38181209, -58.8949415 -13.38181139, 
   -58.89503381 -13.3818107, -58.89512612 -13.38181001, -58.89521843 -13.38180932, 
   -58.89521772 -13.38171894, -58.89531003 -13.38171825, -58.89540234 -13.38171756, 
   -58.89540163 -13.38162718, -58.89540092 -13.38153681, -58.89540022 -13.38144644, 
   -58.89530791 -13.38144713, -58.8952156 -13.38144782, -58.89512329 -13.38144851, 
   -58.89503098 -13.3814492, -58.89493868 -13.3814499, -58.89484637 -13.38145059, 
   -58.89484707 -13.38154096, -58.89484778 -13.38163134, -58.89484849 -13.38172171)
    )
)
for poly in multipolygon:
    print(poly)
```

The problem is when I print my multipolygon, the values are changing.
Here is the output:

```py
(-72.27345684, -72.27336522, -72.27345629999999, -72.27354792, -72.27363954, -72.27373116, -72.27382277, -72.27391439, -72.274006, -72.27409762, -72.27418924, -72.27409816, -72.27400655, -72.27391493, -72.27382331, -72.27373169, -72.27364007, -72.27354845, -72.27345684)
(-72.27657020000001, -72.27666128, -72.27675289, -72.27684451, -72.27693613, -72.27702775, -72.27693666, -72.27702828, -72.2771199, -72.27702881, -72.27693773, -72.27684666, -72.27675504, -72.27666342, -72.2765718, -72.27648018000001, -72.27638858, -72.27629696, -72.27638802999999, -72.27647912, -72.27657020000001)
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Because `-58.89198482 -13.38147202` is `-72.27345684` and not `-58.89198482, -13.38147202`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing commas in the tuples which causes some values to be subtracted

From your code:
-58.89484849 -13.38172171

I'm assuming you mean for it to be -58.89484849, -13.38172171?

otherwise -58.89484849 -13.38172171 = 72.2765702 which matches the printed values

Comment: Commas, and probably also a couple more parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

It does math since this is what you have inside your data structure

-58.89198482 -13.38147202 = -72.27345684

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you are subtracting (-58.89189251 -13.38147271) before printing